# Is it possible to set a custom post type template with code?

Tags: templates

Is it possible to set / change a page's template using WordPress functions?

I have post type (events) where when I create a new post I automatically create a new post and set previously created post to it's parent. I then set it title to ;'Booking' once that's done I want to set it it's template to my booking template to make it totally idiot proof for the end user.

Comment: I think It does not make sense when you use template for custom post type. The custom post type solve the problem of custom template already.

Comment: Good point but I have an event post type which is hierarchical so all the events pages use single-events.php. For every event I have bunch of event pages, it would be nice to just have a separate template for the booking page. If it's not possibly to set the template automatically then I just add my booking code to single-events.php and test if the page title is "booking".